# jQuery - prepend html to list

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to add new elements dynamically to my list.
Using ajax I get the html from my db. I then want to loop through each new `<li>` element and add them to the top of the list one by one.

Here is my code:

```
function recent() {
    var isHovered = $('.most_recent_list').is(":hover");
    if (isHovered == false) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/ajax/get_most_recent/",
            success : function(result) {
                var lis = $(result).find("li");
                lis.each(function(index, li){
                    console.log(li)
                    $('new_arts').prepend(li)
                })

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Here is the result of console.log(li):

[image: result]

How can I use this result to add these li elements to the top of the list?

Thanks!

PS: If you have any tips on how to load the ' ' properly and other special elements I would be grateful :)

Comment: What is `new_arts` id or class?

Comment: new_arts is the class.

Comment: Then use `$('.new_arts')`

Comment: Right... if course. Thanks for helping me see this :)

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED:

I missed the dot in ('.new_arts').